# How to install Microsoft Word template Add-in for all users?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Now I'm developing an application which needs MS Word integration. I've created a template add-in (`.dot file`), now I have to install it.
The docs say I have to copy it to Word startup folder.
I've managed to determine the Word startup folder for `CURRENT` user through `Word.Application` `COM` object.
But the Word integration should work for ALL users of the `PC`.
So my question is: how can I determine the word startup folder for any user of a PC?
Or maybe there is some other way of installing Word add-ins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found on the microsoft forums:

Enumerate existing users in `HKEY_USERS` registry key.

For every user:

- See if `STARTUP-PATH` entry exists in `HKEY_USERS\<user-id>\Software\Microsoft\Office\<word version>.0\Word\Options` Key. If yes, this is user-defined Word startup folder;
- If no, get content of `AppData` entry from `HKEY_USERS\<user-id>\Software\Microsoft\windows\current version\Exlporer\shell folders` key, and then append `Microsoft\Word\Startup` to it. That will be default Word startup folder.